# UBUNTU to WIN 7 without data loss

Tags: installation, boot, windows-7

I accidently compressed my c drive in Windows 7 and ended up with "bootmgr is compressed" error. I had to install Ubuntu to get some files. After that I went online and found some solutions for fixing the 'bootmgr' error. Can I go back to Windows 7 without losing any data? I heard that Ubuntu formats the hdd to a format that Windows does not recognise. What should I do? I am sure I didn't do a full installation of Ubuntu. And also how can I remove Ubuntu completely?

Comment: This seems to be off-topic as it is mostly related to Windows. You may want to ask this over on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/?as=1)

Comment: This is off-topic and probably belongs on SuperUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get a windows 7 DVD or USB-drive.
Boot from it and select Repair.Select *Use Recovery tools*
And from last click on *command prompt*
And type these commands

> Bootrec/FixMBR
>
> Bootrec/RebuildBCD

This will restore your Windows boot-loader and replace grub..

Comment: Thanks for the reply;Would i lose any data?

Comment: No, in fact you can access your Ubuntu files using this software
http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/files/Ext2Read%20ver%202.0/ext2explore%202.0%20beta/

Comment: can i use a Windows XP cd? Can i do it using a Pen drive?

Comment: yes, you can but you will have to install XP on some partition ,use EasyBCD as XP has no such options. This is a tedious method.
It is better if you make windows 7 USB drive using official windows 7 usb tool and a DVD or iso file.

Comment: thank you for all those valuable info.. my problem is solved