# Installing Linux without affecting Window 7

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning

I have Window 7 installed on my laptop and I can install Linux (Ubuntu). I just wanted to install it with the following conditions:

1. At the time of booting I get option for both OS, but if I delete Linux OS it should not affect the booting process of Windows. May be it automatically gain Windows bootloader or if its Grub, its OK.
2. I am not aware of what is "sda" at the time of installation. Can I create "sdb" without destroying Windows partitions and install Linux in this "sdb"? I got free space in my system.

Comment: no its not duplicate.I already mentioned my needs in question

Comment: Your two conditions cover the same thing from slightly different aspect and they're both covered in the linked question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question1:  if you delete Linux and want to not affect the windows bootloader then the Windows bootloader would have to manage both OSs.

Question2: sda, sdb, sdc ... you see a pattern? Everyone is a separate partition, and this is their name. In windows you have C, D, E ...

To make what you are asking I would do like this:

Enter in Linux and do 4 partitions:

1. sda formatted as ext4
2. sdb formatted as linux-swap (with the space double of your ram in the system)
3. sdc formatted as ntfs
4. sdd formatted as ntfs

First instal Ubuntu, when you install you select the mout point / in the sda and then the sdb as swap partition and you install.

Then, install Windows 7 and you will see you have 4 partition in which 2 as ntfs and and probably two unrecognised. In Windows you will have the C drive where the Windows is and the second where you put your data.

Since the Windows 7 is installed secondly and because Windows does what it wants, it will put its bootloader over the Linux one.

Now I have not done lately this (2-3 years ago), and I may not be the best practice, but you get the point.

Comment: Thanks Leon. But window 7 is already installed and i have 4 partitions with important data in it.I also got unused space.Now can I perform the same as you said without harming my data.

Comment: You should install Ubuntu first to avoid reinstalling Grub.

Comment: I changed the second ext4 to linux-swap as it's clearly what was intended.

Comment: I quite understand the purpose of your answer, sick people down rated this.

Comment: @papukaija: That's the problem.I have data in my D:, E: drive.If I do everything from starting I will loose all my data.

Answer (score 0):

Use gparted to change partiton sizes or choose install alongside option [EASY] to install ubuntu.
In case you install Windows 7 after Ubuntu and Ubuntu partitions are **NOT** deleted,
download and burn this ISO file to a CD [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/)

Booting from CD this menu will appear.

[image]

Select 5th option to get old grub menu and boot Ubuntu.
Open terminal and type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

or

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb
```

You should get "operation completed without errors".

then

```
sudo update-grub
```

finally

```
sudo reboot
```

You will get your Ubuntu back.

I hope this makes things safe for you and installing Ubuntu without fear.

Ok in case you delete ubuntu parttions then follow this [Getting windows 7 after deleting ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/314178/162137).

Comment: you will need to enter password on first sudo command, you will not see any asterisks while entering, just press enter after you put it.